Where is meson? build-essential or python3, python3-pip, python3-setuptools, python3-wheel, ninja-build packages are installed but it isn't here
According to installation guides, having executed on my Debian 12:

sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel ninja-build
sudo apt install build-essential

meson should be installed on my system.
And if I do a sudo updatedb + locate meson | xargs -I {} dirname {} |  sort | uniq
I have a lot of outputs:
/data/docker/overlay2/a7ad1e9d584e8675ba05ab724dbf033bd1d83d907756e429f0c2d40f1a919cec/diff/usr/share/mime/text
/data/sauvegardes_par_rsync/home/lebihan/dev/apprentissageDev/python/python_pour_les_mathématiques/ch01/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy
/home/lebihan/Bureau/anaconda3/pkgs/fribidi-1.0.10-h7b6447c_0/info/recipe
/home/lebihan/Bureau/anaconda3/pkgs/glib-2.68.1-h36276a3_0/info/recipe/patches
/home/lebihan/dev/apprentissageDev/python/python_pour_les_mathématiques/ch01/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/opensource/openapi-generator/samples/server/petstore/cpp-pistache/build/PISTACHE-prefix/src/PISTACHE
/home/lebihan/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/clion/plugins
/home/lebihan/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/clion/plugins/clion-meson-plugin
/home/lebihan/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/clion/plugins/clion-meson-plugin/lib
/home/lebihan/.mozilla/firefox/eolge1mk.default-esr/storage/default
/home/lebihan/.mozilla/firefox/eolge1mk.default-esr/storage/default/https+++mesonbuild.com
/home/lebihan/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-sniper/sniper_platform_0.20240307.80401/files/share/mime/text
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194/usr/share/mime/text
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198/usr/share/mime/text
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140/usr/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140/usr/share/mime/text
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143/usr/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143/usr/share/mime/text
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments/lexers
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/__pycache__
/usr/pgadmin4/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygments/lexers
/usr/share/doc/libdav1d-dev/examples
/usr/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs
/usr/share/gtksourceview-5/language-specs
/usr/share/mime/text
/usr/share/vim/vim90/ftplugin
/usr/share/vim/vim90/indent
/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/arch/arm/include/debug
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/dt-bindings/clock
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/dt-bindings/gpio
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/dt-bindings/power
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/dt-bindings/reset
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/dt-bindings/sound
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/linux/firmware
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/linux/firmware/meson
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/linux/soc/amlogic
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/arch/arm/include/debug
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/dt-bindings/clock
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/dt-bindings/gpio
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/dt-bindings/power
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/dt-bindings/reset
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/dt-bindings/sound
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/linux/firmware
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/linux/firmware/meson
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/linux/soc/amlogic

I have a path that looks normal:
echo $PATH
/home/lebihan/anaconda3/bin:/home/lebihan/.local/bin:/home/lebihan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin:/opt/zeppelin-0.10.0-bin-all/bin:/opt/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/bin:/opt/gradle/gradle-6.9.1/bin:/opt/kafka_2.12-3.4.0/bin:/home/lebihan/.local/share/coursier//bin:/home/lebihan/.local/bin/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/lebihan/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts:/home/lebihan/.local/share/coursier/bin

However, my command meson is found nowhere...
$meson
bash: meson : commande introuvable

Where could it be?

You need to install it:
sudo apt install meson

The packages you installed don’t depend on meson, so it wouldn’t have been installed as a dependency.
For future reference, you can use apt-file to find packages providing a given command; in this instance:
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt update
apt-file search bin/meson

(The first two commands are only required if apt-file isn’t already installed.)
